# What files and folders to clean after opencv-4.1.2 build?

Tags: c++, opencv

After building opencv-4.1.2 on windows 7 64 bit. using visual studio 2019 and cmake and python. i have the build folder contains many folders and files.

So what can i delete (files and folders) that are un-necessary to my projects?

The tutorial i've followed to build it says selct 'BUILD_ALL' then 'INSTALL'. when i build install i get a folder named "install".

- I want to know what does INSTALL build do?
- The folder I used to build open_cv contains configue files generated by cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building finished, then in the build folder, you can find a folder calls `install`, so you only keep the `install` folder and delete all other files and folders.

The INSTALL means, all the libs and DLL files will be stored in in a folder that calls the install folder inside the build folder. All you need are in the install folder (libs, dlls, data, ...)

Comment: Thank you first. ok get it. and what about `opencv_contrib`?

Comment: You are welcome! `opencv_contrib` will also put in the install > ... > bin/lib folder, but the `opencv_contrib` DLL files and libs start with `opencv_x*****.dll/lib`

Comment: i want to use opencv from c++ then i don't need python?

Comment: No, also in CMake configuration you can disable create Python wrapper.

Comment: thank you. one last thing: Install is 255 MB while the hole build folder is 11 GB so can I remove all files and folders but install? what i see is modules is the biggest size folder containing big pch files.

Comment: Yes, you can delete all other files and folder, those files are generated while compiling the source code, so it is no longer needed in runtime.